# SQL 2016 - FILESTREAM feature is disabled. (bogus message)

Tags: filestream, sql-server-2016

I'm having problems getting filestream to work. I know how to configure it, and have setup numerous servers running it. For some reason, even though Filestream is definitely enabled, I keep getting this error when trying to restore a filestream enabled database...

FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

I may need some suggestions beyond the obvious.

[image]

[image]

If I try to add a filestream filegroup to a test database, like so...

```
ALTER DATABASE test_fs
  ADD FILEGROUP [FS] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
GO
```

I get...

```
Msg 5591, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
FILESTREAM feature is disabled.
```

If someone could give me some suggestions about what to check, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the confirmation above.  I'm on Windows 10 build 15063.138  and I have SQL 2016 with SP1 and I get the same error.

Thank you for at least validating what I'm seeing.  There doesn't seem to be a work-around posted at this time.

More detail on the bug is posted here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/319528)

Comment: @peterh Why do you say this doesn't answer the question. It provides validation of the issue, and an official link detailing the bug. This is the most helpful response I've had yet, and I think qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @user1751825 I think it could be an answer, although it may be better if you would mention that there is already a workaround on the referred page.

Comment: This site is waaay to caught up in semantics to be useful.  3/4 of the entries I've found in the comments are about the answer someone provided instead of a solution to the original question.  Its all dribble and its a waste of my time to be a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Win10 build 15063.x? If so, there is a bug which effects filestream. Installing SQL 2016 sp1 might help.

Comment: This makes sense. I was using an insider build, but I'm not sure exactly what version. I ended up re-installing Windows 10 Enterprise on the laptop (it was about due for a re-install), and setting everything up again from scratch. SQL 2016 with Filestream is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Fist you have to enable FILESTREAM in GUI as is shown. 
Then create New Query 
In Query Editor, enter the following Transact-SQL code:
    EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
    RECONFIGURE

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923(v=sql.105).aspx
Now it works for me.